# Can you read registry values directly from a Windows command prompt and use these within standard Windows commands?

Tags: command-line, ftp, registry

I want to FTP some files across networks using Windows FTP command prompt and I want to retrieve the FTP parameters from registry keys I have already setup for another related application.

Is there a way to read these parameters in-line direct from the registry as passed values into the FTP command?

Comment: More info required please! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [command line switches on regedit.exe](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/regedit.php) to read/write values. Whether you can do it directly in line for another command I don't know (but I doubt it).

Maybe you can use '>' to store the output in a text file, then read it in for your input to the next command. It would have to be multiple commands in a batch file to do that.

Or, if you can use [reg.exe](http://www.petri.co.il/reg_command_in_windows_xp.htm). (don't think it's installed by default - Can't remember, think it comes with the windows server resource kit or something like that)

(Or just use [powershell](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2003/technologies/management/powershell/default.mspx))

Answer (score 12):

You can read a registry entry into an environment variable using reg query... (the following example is for use in .bat files)

```
@SET MSBUILDDIR=
@for /F "tokens=1,2*" %%i in ('reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersions\3.5" /v "MSBuildToolsPath"') DO (
    if "%%i"=="MSBuildToolsPath" (
        SET "MSBUILDDIR=%%k"
    )
)
@if "%MSBUILDDIR%"=="" exit /B 1
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a great example of what I was trying to do.