# Command Line Variable for .NET Framework

Tags: .net, batch-file, command-line

I'm trying to write a batch file that installs a windows service using installutil.exe.  I would like to use the installutil.exe that is in the latest version of the .Net Framework (located in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319 on my machine).

Is there an easy way to change the directory in the command line to the latest .NET Framework directory?

For example, I know using **cd %WINDIR%** will give me **C:\Windows**.  What would I type to get to the latest .Net Framework Directory?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using Reed Copseys advice about inspecting the registry I found a sample on [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9422501/1523851) about how to read the registry from a batch file.

Here is my batch file that finds the install directory for the .Net 4 Framework and installs my service:

```
@SET INSTALLUTILDIR=
@for /F "tokens=1,2*" %%i in ('reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full" /v "InstallPath"') DO (
    if "%%i"=="InstallPath" (
        SET "INSTALLUTILDIR=%%k"
    )
)

%INSTALLUTILDIR%\installutil MyService.exe
```

And here is the link where you can find the registry key for the specific version of the framework you are looking for: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/kbarticle.aspx?id=318785

Answer (score 1):

There is no environment variable you can use as a "standard" replacement like that.  The way most installers do it is by [inspecting the registry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/199783/65358) for the Framework installation path.